# Selenium IDE - Test if error pop-up does NOT appear

Tags: selenium, testing, vaadin, selenium-ide, ui-testing

In my Vaadin web application tested by Selenium IDE (*not Vaadin Testbench - I am aware of it, but I dont wanna use it*) I want to verify, that error message pop-up was NOT triggered => so the test can continue running.

I have no problem with identifying the pop-up. Its locator is

```
css=div.v-Notification.failure
```

and I have checked that Selenium IDE recognizes presence of this element correctly.

But there is a problem with delay in my webapp. When Selenium IDE clicks a GUI element, the request for data is sent to ESB. When the ESB is turned off or some error occurs, webapp is notified and it displays the error popup. **However**, this doesn't occure immideately, processing of the request takes some time.

So testing `assertElementNotPresent` always passes, as the pop up is not yet generated right after GUI click. I know the article about [AJAX testing in Selenium](https://www.infoq.com/articles/testing-ajax-selenium), but it doesn't help me in this case either, because `waitForElementNotPresent` also immideately assumes the pop up is not there, although it appears just a few moments later... And obviously I can't use opposite `waitForElementPresent`, because I want my test to continue when the error pop up is not there.

The only thing that is "working" is hardcoded `pause` step in test, but this is not the good way (refer to linked article, if you doubt why...also I don't want my test suite to take ages with a lot of pauses).

Any other ideas or approaches, that could enlight me a bit?

Comment: The original issue is that you do not know when the popup will show up, so other than using certain timeout with `waitForElementPresent(popup) if(popup = null) proceed`, I don't think there is a better approach. Unless you know what the next thing coming, then you can use `waitForElementPresent(anyElementOnNewPage)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a variant with Selenium IDE flowcontrol.

Check this out:

```
storeEval               | 0                               | i
storeEval               | false                           | x
while                   | ${x} == false 
pause                   | 1000
storeElementPresent     | css=div.v-Notification.failure  | x
storeEval               | ${i}+1                          | i
storeEval               | if (${i}>30) {true} else {${x}} | x
endWhile
assertElementNotPresent | css=div.v-Notification.failure
```

This will wait for popup for about 30 second and will fail the test immediately on popup appearance. I am pretty sure that there should be a shorter way to perform it. But it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you're trying to recognize the presence of the element. In this case, try using `assertNotVisible` and `waitForNotVisible`

Comment: sadly, this doesnt make any change...if IDE asks "is the element not visible?" right after GUI click the answer is "yes, it is not" - it appears few moments later, but test already passed...i need some delay, but preferably not hardcoded `pause` which is either unnecesarily long or too short...